# A C++ class-function

Tags: c++, class

A simple c++ file and the class TT has two methods.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TT{ 
    public:
        TT(const string& str);
        template<class T>T Read(const string& key)const;
        template<class T>T Read(const string& key, const T& value)const;
};

TT::TT(const string& str){
    cout<<str<<endl;
}

template<class T>T TT::Read(const string& key)const{
    std::cout<<key<<std::endl;
    return 1;
}

template<class T>T TT::Read(const string& key, const T& value)const{
    std::cout<<key<<'\t'<<value<<std::endl;
    return value;
}

int main(void){
    TT tt("First");

    tt.Read("Hello", 12);
    return 1;
}
```

If replace the

```
tt.Read("Hello world!", 12);
```

with

```
tt.Read("Hello world!");
```

in **main()**

G++ says:

> new.cc:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘TT::Read(const char [5])’

Why G++ cann't find the **Read(const string& key)const** method?

Thanks!

Comment: it just worked on G++ 4.7.2

Comment: @billz, it fails for me: http://ideone.com/ymUPB5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to define a function that returns a T:

```
template<class T>
T TT::Read(const string& key) const
{
    std::cout << key << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

However, you always return an `int` from this function. You either need to call it like so:

```
tt.Read<int>("Hello");
```

Or remove the template definition, as it makes no sense here.

Comment: You just said my answer but with more words. +1

Comment: The version with a parameter lets the compiler derive the template parameter `T` automatically; without the parameter you have to give the template type explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `template<class T>T Read(const string& key)const;` is templated on type T but T only appears as the return type.

If it is your intention to manually bake a return type into your function (and it seems like it is from the appearance of `return 1;`), you can change the declaration to something like:

```
int Read(const string& key) const;
```

Otherwise you must specify the templated type manually in the call as so:

```
tt.Read<int>("Hello");
```

This boils down to the fact that a function cannot have a templated type deduced when that templated type appears solely in return.

The C++ standard says it in a way much less easy on the eyes in the section titled:

`Explicit template argument specification [temp.arg.explicit]`

> If all of the template arguments can be deduced, they may all be
>   omitted; in this case, the empty template argument list <> itself may
>   also be omitted. In contexts where deduction is done and fails, or in
>   contexts where deduction is not done, if a template argument list is
>   specified and it, along with any default template arguments, identifies
>   a single function template specialization, then the template-id is an
>   lvalue for the function template specialization.

```
template<class X, class Y> X f(Y);

int i = f<int>(5.6); // Y is deduced to be double
int j = f(5.6); // ill-formed: X cannot be deduced
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because when dealing with templates, the compiler would like to know what the return function is and it can't figure it out even though it returns 1 which is an int. Technically `return 1` could be an error as it doesn't know what the return value SHOULD be.

Use `tt.Read<int>("Hello");`